# Converting images between colour spaces

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, image, opencv, image-processing

In my book, the method to convert a image from one colour space to another is `cv::cvtColor()`. But, I can't find that method in `cv` namespace! In other words, I am using VS 2010 express, and the intellisense also got no idea about this method!

I am using opencv 2.4, so is this method is moved to another namespace or something? Please see the following, the method if not in CV

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat m;
    //cv::cvtColor(Mat,Mat,int)  is not there!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a look at `imgproc.hpp` :

```
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
```

You may also need to add `opencv_imgproc24x.lib` or `opencv_imgproc24xd.lib` to your linker inputs